# how to convert DateTime to a specified Format in windows phone 8

Tags: string, c#-4.0, datetime, windows-phone-8

I have this date format MM/dd/yyyy. The problem is, when i convert it displays 
05-12-2013.I want to display formate like 05/12/2013.
How can i correctly format it to: 05/12/2013?

My c# code is

```
 DateTime dt1 = (DateTime)obj["FromDate"];
 DateTime dtlocal1 = dt1.ToLocalTime();
 tbFromDate.Text = dtlocal1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, your code formats the date correctly for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a forward slash character (`/`), that tells .Net to use the date separator that is specific to the current culture.  [Read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator).

You can use the invariant culture, where the separator is always a forward slash:

```
dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Alternatively, you can specify in the format string to specifically use the forward slash character instead of the culture-specific date separator:

```
dt.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy")
```